# can one spider handle multiple items and multiple pipelines?

Tags: python, web, scrapy

New to scrapy.There are something confused me:what's the relationship between spiders,pipelines and items?

1.should one pipeline handle only one specific item or it can handle multiple items?

2.how to use one spider to crawl multiple items or I should use one spider just to crawl one item?

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment? This is a legit beginner question, it looks very much inside the scope of the site and will probably be helpful to other beginners. It doesn't matter if the answer is in a document elsewhere, the question still stands. I'm curious as to why you think the question is unclear or not useful.

Comment: so,if there are two pipeline A and B (A has higher priority), one item will go first A then go B? What if I want to a item just go B ? should I dropitem in A or just do nothing let the item pass?

Comment: Yes, the numbers you use when configuring the pipelines represent the order, so smaller numbers are first. And yeah, items will always go through the pipeline, so you just let the item pass when you don't want to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Item** refers to an item of data that it's scraped. You can also call it a record or an entry.

**Spider** is the thing that does crawling (starting requests and following links) and scraping (extracting data items from responses). They can schedule whatever amount of requests and extract whatever amount of items as you want, there isn't any limit.

**Item pipelines** are an abstraction to process the items that are extracted by a spider. The idea is that you can combine different "pipes" through which the data items will come through, and then you'll arrange them in a way that will accomplish whatever you need. Examples of use cases for pipelines are applying validation constraints, saving data into a database, doing some clean-up on the data (e.g., remove HTML tags), etc.

So, recapping:

**Spiders** extract data **items**, which Scrapy send one by one to a configured **item pipeline** (if there is possible) to do post-processing on the items.